# Trying to restore previous session in Google Chrome, without Last Tabs/Last Session files

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, session-restore

So I had a massive amount of tabs/windows open in Google Chrome, went away for a bit, and Google Chrome had closed. I reopened Google Chrome, which gave me no option to restore the session despite being set to "Continue where I left off". I did some Googling, which suggested I go to the C:\Users(username)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default folder and Rename the Last Tabs/Last Session files to Current and forcequitting Chrome and reopening. However there are no files with these names in this folder, what could the issue be?

Answer (score 2):

Don't take my word for it, but if I had to guess, after a recent update what used to be Last Tabs/Last Session is now kept within the "Sessions" folder of the same directory. It should have files named "Session_(series of digits)" and "Tabs_(series of digits)", and they appear to contain the links to tabs I had open during my last session. No idea how to use that to restore them though, other than manually, I didn't personally try to rename them.

UPDATE: I tested renaming the files, and it seems to successfully restore the last session. Interestingly, the older pair of files seems to also contain links from the session before last, though I have no idea how to restore those.